# How can I use google play services in a maven project?

Tags: android, maven, google-play-services

Somebody can give me a step by step tutorial about how can I use google play services in a maven project? 
I've added two dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
    <version>4</version>
    <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
    <version>4</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

The apklib and jar appear in maven repository but the com.google.android.gms.R class is not generated.

I receive NoClassDefFoundError. How can I put the com.google.android.gms in the gen folder?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [Android Maven SDK Deployer](https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer) for more than just Google Play Services

### ".apklib" with android-maven-plugin <3.8.1

Btw you should use version 13.0.0 and not 4

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
  <version>13.0.0</version>
  <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
  <version>13.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

### ".aar" with android-maven-plugin 3.8.2+

With android-maven-plugin 3.8.2 you can also use the play services aar

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>play-services</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.30</version>
  <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I just used it. It's work great, however, they should update to allow build addons for individual profiles.

Comment: I believe it was previously like that. you can submit pull requests anyway ;)

Comment: In general, version shouldn't be `13.0.0` or `14.0.0` or similar. Those were seemingly derived from the Android API version, Play Services has a **separate version number***. I'm looking at the jar file I got with the Android API version 18, and it is `5.0.77-000`. Theoretically that is the correct version number not `18.0.0`. Now, I don't know what that Android Maven SDK Deployer thingie does internally, I don't use it. If it installs the jars using the Android API version into your local repo, then of course it'll work that way. :P

Comment: I accidentally +1 your comment. You should research before commenting.

Comment: Just to weigh in on this: the "Google Repository" that you can download in the SDK manager uses `7.8.0`, `8.1.0` and so forth. So that's the version number I'll be using I think. +1 for a great answer Benoit!

Answer (score 6):

After importing the google-play-services_lib project into your Eclipse workspace and making it a library you need to setup the maven build process.

Make a zip file of the "google-play-services_lib" folder and call it "google-play-services_lib.apklib"

```
  + google-play-services_lib.apklib
     + src
     + res
     + AndroidManifest.xml
     + project.properties
```

Open the command prompt and go to the folder where the zip file is and type the following command. This will install the apklib into you local maven repository.

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=google-play-services_lib.apklib -DgroupId=com.google.android.gms -DartifactId=google-play-services -Dversion=14.0.0 -Dpackaging=apklib

Now you need to install the google-play-services jar into your local repository.

> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=google-play-services.jar -DgroupId=com.google.android.gms -DartifactId=google-play-services -Dversion=14.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar

Go back into Eclipse and open your android pom file and enter the following dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
  <version>14.0.0</version>
  <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>    

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
  <version>14.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now you can run your maven package command to have output update with the google play jar and the apklib merged into your apk file.

> mvn package -Pandroid -Psign

Answer (score 3):

Checkout the link given by Jake Wharton. It requires 2 steps. In the first you deploy the artifact to the local maven repository and then reference it from within you app/pom.xml

https://github.com/JakeWharton/gms-mvn-install

HTH

Comment: As of this comment writing, the gms-mvn-install is deprecated.