# Adding Google Cloud Messaging to existing Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, android-library, google-cloud-messaging

The android docs recommend you add the gcm library project located at `$ANROID_HOME/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/`, however I don't want to clutter my eclipse workspace with a useless project.

After checking the contents of the project I noticed that there is no real code, only a jar (`google-play-services.jar`) and a bunch of resource files.

My question is: If I'm only going to use GCM, is it possible to just put that jar in my maven repo as opposed to importing the Android library project?

Comment: This might be duplicated please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486877/how-can-i-use-google-play-services-in-a-maven-project

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your question. To be able to use GCM, you just need to Add `google-play-services.jar` in your project path. 
I successfully added the library by `Project>Properties>Java Build Path > Libraries (tab) > Add External Jars` and selected the library from `C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\libs`

Hope this helps/