# Google Play Services with Maven?

Tags: android, maven, aar

I'm some kind of confused. I want to install Google Play Services for Android and found this question: [How can i use google play services in a maven project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486877/how-can-i-use-google-play-services-in-a-maven-project)

There is a reference to https://github.com/mosabua/maven-android-sdk-deployer/ which provides a project to install a lot of mavenized APIs. So I downloaded and built it to get one of the latest Google Play Services API but when I add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
    <artifactId>play-services</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.89</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

to my project, I get a "support-v4-19.1.0.jar" as dependency which includes neither any Google Play Services classes nor do I have any of those layout files supplied with Google Services API. For example: When I look to https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html, and read the ProGuard part, then there must be at least a class called SafeParcelable, but this included project by Maven does not even have the common package where this class is included. I wonder what's going on here.

The project play-services-5.0.89.aar exists in the Maven repository. But how do I use this? Is there any additional task to do since it's aar or something?

**[UPDATE]**
Ok, it seems that's only an Eclipse problem, because **com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext())** is compilable by Maven although Eclipse doesn't find it. That means that the Google Play Services API works within the project.

**[UPDATE 2]**
Meanwhile I figured out that aar is not supported by Eclipse. But I use a little trick to use apklib and aar (which is supported by android-maven-plugin) with Eclipse. I unpack the package (in Maven repository) and import it as library into Eclipse. Then I add the library reference into the main project's properties. Eclipse finds the classes of these libraries then, so no erroneous Eclipse project anymore (even content assist works) and you can even build it by Maven when you use the android-maven-plugin. In other words: You only need to import aar and apklib as libraries into Eclipse due to code writing to not have an erroneous project. For the build process all this doesn't matter, since Maven does all your build handling.