# How to add Google Play Service Library as a library project in Maven

Tags: android, google-maps, maven

I work on android project. Firstly I have generated pom.xml to convert it into maven project. In pom.xml, I have to use Google Play Service Library as a library project for displaying map so that I have added dependency of Google Play Service Library in pom.xml. but when I am using mvn clean install command, It will **throw warning**

The POM for com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:jar:$(google-p
lay-services-version) is missing, no dependency information available

**with error message** :- 
Failed to execute goal on project AndroidMap: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.androidMap:AndroidMap:apk:3.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to
find com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:jar:$(google-play-services-vers
ion) in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of googlePlayService has
elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
Here is my code:

```
<properties>
        <google-play-services-version>6.5</google-play-services-version>
</properties>

<dependency>
         <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
          <artifactId>google-play-services</artifactId>
          <version>$(google-play-services-version)</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17486877/how-can-i-use-google-play-services-in-a-maven-project ?

Comment: Try putting just 6.5 in version tag instead of the properties variable.

Comment: I have tried above link but it will not work for me giving error:- Failed to execute goal on project MapApp: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.androidMap:AndroidMap:apk:2.6.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:apklib:$(google-play-services-version), com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:jar:$(google-play-services-version):                                                                                                I have also put 6.5 version, but it is throwing same error.

Comment: Remaining error message is :- Failure to
find com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:apklib:6.5 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of googlePlayService has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]